# How does a process terminate after it tries to execute an illegal instruction?

Tags: cpu, operating-systems

When a process executes an illegal instruction (like division by zero, or trying to access a forbidden memory space), this is detected by the CPU, then the
CPU saves what it has to save and changes the IP (instruction pointer) to the adress of the OS routine which is in charge of that particular error. Then the process abnormally terminates (or not?).

I would like to know two things:
1. Does the process that tries to execute illegal instruction **always** abnormally terminate?
2. Is the termination carried out by the OS or CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No.
2. Exception occurs in CPU, then CPU transfer the control to OS.

We call this event an "exception". DivisionByZero is a typical exception.

CPU operates with opcodes, not with complete process/software. OS transfers 
the next opcode to the CPU. If the CPU response is an exception, OS handles what will follow next: termination, or run forward. Also process can set up OS to manage the exceptions itself, in this case the CPU exception received by the OS and forwarded to process, and process can manage the next step.

But this is a very composite topic, hard to sum it in few words.

Comment: @Plajdo : Thank you, feel free to edit my replies, I have not used English for a long time.